# How to detect if server seems busy in Laravel

Tags: laravel, server

Right now I don't have time to optimize and to upgrade servers and once or twice a month the server reaches critical load (mysql basically) and it goes very very slow in production mode.

I want to show a static message saying the server is too busy when that happens. how to get it in Laravel ?

Comment: Basically you can create a cron to send some request to database each day. If it takes too much then put your app in maintenance mode. And if it turns back to normal, then disable maintenance mode

Comment: Check this answer which uses `/proc/loadavg`: [Using /proc/loadavg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/632299/10441671). [How can my PHP script tell whether the server is busy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632245/how-can-my-php-script-tell-whether-the-server-is-busy)

Comment: You search the internet for *detect if server is busy*. That's what I did.

Comment: I found this but fuction sys_getloadavg can't running in laravel
    $load = sys_getloadavg();
    if ($load[0] > 80) {
       header('HTTP/1.1 503 Too busy, try again later');
       die('Server too busy. Please try again later.');
    }

Comment: Yes there are other answers as well, like the one I posted above using `/proc/loadavg`. Have you looked at that?